# array sort changing curent and old variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

JS Source:

```
var c1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var c2=c1;
c1.sort();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '1 -> '+c1+'<br>2 -> '+c2;
```

RESULT:
1 -> BMW,Saab,Volvo
2 -> BMW,Saab,Volvo

I need to be:
1 -> BMW,Saab,Volvo
2 -> Saab,Volvo,BMW

Comment: Your variables are referring to the exact same object (the array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
var c2=c1;
```

you are actually making `c2` point to the same object referred by `c1`. And then you are changing the `c1` Array object. Since `c2` and `c1` refer the same object, `c1` and `c2` will print the same.

You need to make a copy of the Array object. You can use `c1.slice()` to do that, like this

```
var c2 = c1.slice();
```

Now `c2` refers to a copy of the `c1` array. So, changes made to the `c1` will not affect the `c2` object.

Comment: Thank you very much!(Sorry for my english - is bad)

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
var c2=c1;
```

...doesn't create a copy of the array, it creates a second reference to the same underlying array object. So modifications that you make via *either* variable will affect the same array, whether that be sorting, adding elements, or whatever.

Fortunately it's easy to create a copy of an array:

```
var c2 = c1.slice();
```

The [`.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a copy of a portion of an array, or, if you call it with no arguments (or with just a start index of `0`) it copies the whole array. So then the `c1` and `c2` variables will refer to two different arrays and you can sort or otherwise modify one without changing the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just use slice(0):

```
var c1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var c2=c1.slice(0);
c1.sort();
alert(c1);
alert(c2);
```

Here a sample:

> http://jsfiddle.net/c3161930/

Best regards,
Felipe